# Fazer verificação de ID com um único foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, table, laravel-blade

Gostaria de saber se tem um certo `id`, sem precisar fazer dois `foreach`

```
  @forelse($surveys as $survey)
          @forelse($survey->users as $user)
               @if($user->id == $auth()->user())
                    AÇÃO
           @empty
           @endfor
  @empty
  @endfor
```

Tenho uma tabela `N pra N` de `survey` e `user`. gostaria de uma solução do tipo

```
 @if($survey->users->contains('id',auth()->user()->id))
```

Mas nao consegui resultado, eu verifico isso na `blade`, alguem tem uma solução?

Comment: Você não pode montar um select pra retornar somente os dados que se encaixam nesses casos?

Answer (score 0):

Sim tem uma solucão, cria o metodo contains lá no survey, exemplo:

```
//survey

public function contains($column = 'id', $value = 0)
{
    $users = $this->users;
    foreach($users as $user) 
    {
        //existe algum user com $column, $value ?
        if($user->{$column} === $value) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

no blade seria algo do tipo

```
$survey->contains('id',auth()->user()->id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, creio que tu estejas pensando ao contrário. Tu queres pegar os surveys do usuário logado não? Usa lazy eagerload.

```
$user = \Auth::user();
$user->load('surveys');

foreach($user->surveys as $survey)...
```

Dessa forma não precisa usar o método 'contains' da Collection.

Referencia:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading